# PHP OR and AND function have strange behaviou

Tags: php, logic, operators

```
    $q = TRUE and FALSE;  // or use AND
    var_dump($q);
```

returns FALSE

```
    $q = FALSE or TRUE;   // or use OR
    var_dump($q);
```

returns FALSE

Replacing AND with && and OR with || gives the opposite and correct result. I have tested this with v5 and v7 with identical results.
What is the difference between the functions AND and OR and && and || ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php as the first point of rerefence. Look in particular at the examples and the remarks about precedence.

Comment: N.B. `$q = TRUE and FALSE;` returns `true`, not `false`.

Comment: That would be nice but it did not!

Comment: I went to a sandbox at [link]https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b8or and entered   <?php
    $q = TRUE and FALSE;
    var_dump($q);
    echo $q;      and got the result bool(true)
1 so it is not just my php.

Comment: Are you sure? Demo: https://3v4l.org/1KEJX

Comment: As a human, I make plenty of mistakes, but this looks real.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're saying. Please find a way to prove the assertion that it produces a different result. My demo shows otherwise. I can only assume that you have indeed somehow made a mistake :-)

Answer (score 1):

That is because there is precedence of operators in play here.

&& has higher precedence over AND
|| has higher precedence over OR

check the documentation for PHP operators here
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Thanks, but in each case there is just one operator so I think it is not precedence. The problem started as two operators but when I discovered the problem with a single operator, I posted that.

Comment: @Iain I think you've misunderstood how precedence can work. the order of evaluation can still be different. Did you read the examples in the documentation link I gave? It does actually show you how/why it happens.

Comment: Well it's not really precedence between two different ANDs or ORs at play, there is another operator =(Assignment operator) which has less precedence than &&/|| and higher precedence than AND or OR operators , hence the baffling outputs :)

Comment: Thanks, GSM. Sorry to have dismissed ADyson earlier but precedence does indeed solve it. The difference between AND and && is huge. I have learned a lot about php this last week!  Case solved. Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran

```
var_dump(FALSE or TRUE);
```

and it returned:

```
 bool(true)
```

I think you did something wrong.

Comment: `$q = FALSE or TRUE; var_dump($q);` will return `bool(false)`

Comment: `var_dump(FALSE or TRUE);` returns `false` - Demo: https://3v4l.org/1KEJX

Comment: I ran     
<?php
$q = FALSE or TRUE;
var_dump($q);
echo $q;
var_dump(FALSE or TRUE);   
and got  
bool(false)
bool(true)
It gives different results depending on whether there is an intermediate variable!